# How can I pass an object array to a method in another class so this method uses it as a normal array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, instance, crud

I am pretty new to java and programming in general so sorry if I confuse some concepts, in my code I have an object called **cr** which is an array in the class **Menu** constructed from the class **ControllerRoute**, this instance I require to pass to a method in the class **UpdateAndDelete** that does the process of update and delete of a CRUD, but the code in the method doesn't read as an array but as an object **ControllerRoute**. I did try having different names in the parameter and using *super.cr* but it didn't work for me.

The Menu is to use the different actions of the CRUD, but here is the update
part, which is the one giving problems.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Menu{
private ControllerRoute cr = new ControllerRoute(100);
UpdateAndDelete ud = new UpdateAndDelete();

   public void updateRoute(){
      ControllerRoute ur = new ControllerRoute(0);
      int id;
      id = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter an Id"));
      ud.updateRoutes(id, cr);
      }
}
```

Route alongside ControllerRoute are the classes used to create the array and
from where the object **cr** comes.

```
public class Route{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   
   public Route () {}
   
   public Route(int id, String name){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

```
public class ControllerRoute extends Menu{
   Route[] routes;
   
   public ControllerRoute(int size){
      routes = new Route[size];
   }
}
```

UpdateAndDelete is the method that is asking for **cr** to do the process of update and delete parts of the array. Here is where in every place that has **cr** in it an error appears because either it can't found the symbol nor can recognize cr as an array.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class UpdateAndDelete{

   public Route updateRoutes(int id, ControllerRoute cr){
      int pos = -1;
      String nwname;
      for(int i=0; i<cr.length; i++){
           if(id == cr[i].getId()){
            pos=i;
           }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Errors found:

***error: cannot find symbol*** on the line:
for(int i=0; i<cr.length; i++){

***UpdateAndDelete.java:14: error: array required, but ControllerRoute found*** in the lines:
if(id == cr[i].getId()){

cr[pos] = new Route(id, nwname);

I first tried changing the parameter, either the name of the array or the type alongside it between int, String, Array. Route[] and the final one being ControllerRoute.

After that I tried using super.cr to see if I could take it directly from menu, but it gave problems with methods like .length

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class UpdateAndDelete extends Menu{

   public Route updateRoutes(int id, ControllerRoute cr){
      int pos = -1;
      String nwname;
      for(int i=0; i<super.cr.length; i++){
           if(id == super.cr[i].getId()){
            pos=i;
           }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

This gives the same errors.

Other thing that I tried with the super was trying create another array in **UpdateAndDelete** and use super.cr to translate it's value to it (*example: pj = super.cr*), but it gave out the error that the array wasn't compatible with **ControllerRoute**

Comment: Just some general comments before I dig into this: 1. Decent indentation would help, the code is hard to read and therefore it's hard to help you.  2. There's quite a lot of code here to look at and if it's possible to trim this down that would also be helpful.  Please at least make an attempt at a [mcve] so that people can help you faster.

Comment: So the first two errors are just syntax errors / typos.  `cr` is not an array.  So the first line makes no sense, and the second line `cr[i].getId()` is just wrong: `cr.getId()`  just lose the [] square brackets.  It looks a bit like you copied some code from elsewhere that happened to use arrays, and you didn't understand what you were copying.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and help, I tried to cut it a little for what I thought wasn't neccessary, and I will do more research on how to order codes so its more readable. About the code itself, indeed, I spend some time looking around at examples of this type of code to practice it and I might not catch much of it or just pieces of different techniques, about the cr. May I ask, if it isn't an array, would it be more practical to search a way to make it fit or pass it to an array, or try to re-do the code implementing an actual array in it's place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ControllerRoute is not an array. it has an attribute which is array. try to write a getter for routes in ControllerRoute and use that to get the array.
ud.updateRoutes(id, cr.getRoutes());

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out and it appears to now be able to catch the cr and pass it to the method, it does appear that it doesn´t work as an arrey like it has been said on the answers, but this helped with that first part, thanks.